# Yii2 Team Workflow

Tags: php, git, yii2, composer-php

When working on a new Yii project, team members are always adding new composer dependencies, database changes, and updates to each environment.

At the moment, I run the following commands each time I pull changes:

`git pull`

`composer install`

`./yii init`

`./yii migrate`

Is this the correct workflow? Is this efficient?
It feels like it could be much better somehow, is there any way to know if I need to migrate/init/or install composer dependencies before running the commands or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [Deployer](http://deployer.org/) - and wrote a blog post about using it with Yii here:
[Deploying Yii with Deployer](https://jacmoe.dk/blog/2016/january/deploying-yii-with-deployer/)

That might or might not be what you want, but I like that workflow. :)

I wrote an advanced template with Deployer support where the init script has been replaced by Deployer tasks.
And it does vendor update and migrations too.

Direct link to the package here: [yii2-app-advanced-deployer](https://packagist.org/packages/jacmoe/yii2-app-advanced-deployer)

EDIT:

To answer your question - if you're not into a full on deployment script - is that you only need to run the `init` script once.
And, of course, perform a composer install and a migration.

Then, after each pull of code, you will see whether or not you need to perform a composer install or not (composer.json has changed) and whether or not you need to migrate up (a migration script has been added).

Simple enough :)

If you are developing an application, consider committing composer.lock to the repository so that you all are using the same version of dependencies.

Comment: that post is great ! Thanks @jacmoe for sharing it ! I never could figure out  how to do such a thing as I didn't knew about the existence of projects like Deployer.

Comment: If you are using my Deployer script for the advanced app, please do not hesitate to report bugs, suggest features or even issue PRs. :)

Comment: But Deployer is indeed a great tool :)